# How do I show the line that caused the exception, not where the exception occured?

Tags: php, exception

If a function throws an exception because the calling code does not call it properly, how do I make the error show the file and line number of the calling code instead of (or in addition to) the line where the exception is thrown?

ie:

```
class MyClass {
   public function __call($MethodName, $Parameters)
   {
       if (!property_exists($this, $PropertyName))            
         throw new Exception('Error Getting Property: ' . $PropertyName . ' does not exist!');
       // THIS line number appears in the exception, but
       // is useless because it isn't the problem.
   }
}


$MyClass = new MyClass();
// THIS line number should be in the exception,
// since its the line that's wrong.
$MyClass->GetSomethingThatDoesNotExist();
```

Comment: Do you have a debugging extension like Xdebug? It shows up in [its stack trace](http://ideone.com/06NORm) for me.

Comment: if you put your function call in try catch block .. the stack trace will give you the file and location where the error occurred..

Answer (score 1):

There's a few options for this;

### Roll your own

Using the [debug_print_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) function in PHP you can make something to display your own output.

### Pre built libraries to output the stack trace

You can also install the awesome [whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops) package to get a nicer output of the problem and how the code got there, check it out here: https://github.com/filp/whoops

### Xdebug

This is the preferred due to better var_dump() output among other huge advantages. Once installed, it just makes all your debugging and error output much more insightful and easier to read.

Install [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/install) to display a more verbose output of the whole flow of events that lead to the issue, known as the stack trace.